# Proof of identity in Montgomery and Vaughan

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-zeta

In Multiplicative Number Theory, Montgomery and Vaughan provide an identity for Riemann's zeta function.
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_{1}^{\infty}\left \{ u \right \}u^{-s-1}du$$
They then state

[image]

But it seems to me there are several steps missing. Why does that sufficies to prove the inequality? Why are they only using the $\int_{1}^{\infty}\left \{ u \right \}u^{-s-1}du$ part of the identity? How does that prove the original inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing step is to express this intergral  with the fractional part in terms of the zeta function, using original identity:
$$\int_1^\infty\{u\} u^{-\sigma- 1}du = \frac{1}{\sigma - 1} - \frac{\zeta(\sigma)}{\sigma}.$$

Then plug-in into the chain of inequalities:
$$0 \le \frac{1}{\sigma - 1} - \frac{\zeta(\sigma)}{\sigma} < \frac{1}{\sigma}.$$
By re-arranging we obtain what's required. A minor point is that we requiry the first inequality in the chain to be strict, but clearly this is true.